# What is the standard way to use RPC in Android?

Tags: android, rpc

What is the standard way to use RPC in Android?
The official way to do RPC in Android seems for me AIDL.
Is that correct?

First of all I am quite new to Android. But the start is good. I am warming up with the functions I already know from Java.
Now I want to go further and use some advanced techniques with some of my already existing software in Java.

Here’s the scenario. I have a little Java server which runs an object orientated version of RPCs called SIMON. Now I want to combine it with Android.
Means on an Android device I want to run a little app as client which gets its information from my server.

I read some instructions to program a client and a server for android.
But both are running on android which I don’t want to.

Does anybody know how to combine RPC between Android and Java?
Maybe some links or hints in which direction I can search should do the trick.
Right now I am a little bit lost and combine these two worlds.

I have already came across REST, JSON, XML-RPC, SOAP who needs external libraries I don’t want to use.
I want to stick with the standard way of Android to keep it “Original” Android. Whatever.
The pure Android code is my goal in this stage.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no "standard" way to do RPC to a server from Android.
The AIDL that you mention is for doing RPC to another process on the same device.

As you have found, there is a plethora of serialization formats and libraries supporting them for doing communication between an Android app and a server - so take your pick.

I have no proof of this, but I would guess that a very large majority of developers would use JSON over HTTPS, possibly REST, possibly not. But there's also nothing wrong with using Avro, gRPC, Protocol Buffers, Apache android-json-rpc, or anything else - use whatever works best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for a simple way to do remote RPC in android. After searching for quite a bit I finally used [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

GRPC: https://grpc.io/

There is a learning curve both on the server side and client side implementation, however, it is robust and strict with code generation. I have never had any issues.